# Download image from Android using HttpConnection got 410, but postman got 200

Tags: java, android, https, httpconnection

I face a problem during downlonading an image in Android.

The problematic image link: 
https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952

I can use postman to download the image successfully (200).
But when I code in Android, using HttpConnection, it responds me with error status code 410.
(And then triggers FileNotFounedException.)

Below is my code,

```java
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        // always check HTTP response code first
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
            int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                            disposition.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        fileURL.length());
            }

            System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
            System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
            System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
            System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            System.out.println("File downloaded");
            httpConn.disconnect();
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        } else {
            httpConn.disconnect();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error code: " + responseCode);
        }
```

My code can successfully download images from Imgur, but as for this link, it fails.

Please share any idea, I do appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a simple reason.

The cause is not at your Java program side but at the server side.

The server rejects your connection by responding `HTTP 410 Gone`.

To dodge the server's behavior, just set any popular `User-Agent` string on your request before doing actual request.

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setRequestProperty(
    "User-Agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; ja-JP-mac; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"
);
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna download image and show it on `ImageView` you can use [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/). its pretty easy to implement, on glide you can just

```java
Glide.with(context).load("https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952").into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to download image from URL

```
// DownloadImage AsyncTask
    private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

            String imageURL = URL[0];

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                // Download Image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
```

// set this bitmap to image view
          // NOW USE THIS BITMAP TO SAVE IMAGE IN MEMORY, I SAVED IN INTERNAL MEMORY

```
                if (result != null) {
                    File destination = new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(),
                            "profile" + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        destination.createNewFile();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
                        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                        fos.write(bitmapdata);
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        selectedFile = destination;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }



        }
    }
```

Now call this method like this

```
new DownloadImage().execute("https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952");
```